# Unable to read all JSON attributes

Tags: java, json

I have the following json jsonobject. I can read some but not all the attributes. if i print the JSONObj i get:
JSONObj :

```
{
   "@priority":"50",
   "flags":{
      "scheduleStatus":"DURING"
   },
   "@startDate":"2013-10-15T12:30:57.493Z",
   "description":"UserReconcile",
   "@distributionStrategy":"OFFER",
   "name":"UserReconcile",
   "itemContext":{
      "appName":"MyProcess",
      "appInstance":"pvm:0a12iq",
      "activityName":"UserReconcile",
      "appID":"_-hYCETV8EeOr4-yR8gXd7g",
      "activityID":"pvm:001im4"
   }
}
```

I am able to get values for @priority, description and a few others. I am unable to get "activityID" which is the last key.

My code that gets values ok is:

```
priority=jsonObj.getString("@priority");
startDate =jsonObj.getString("@startDate");
workDesc=jsonObj.getString("description");
```

and this fails:

```
amxref = jsonObj.getString("activityID");
```

Comment: Try to get the value of itemContext and process activityID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an expanded view of your JSON:

```
{
    "@priority": "50",
    "flags": {
        "scheduleStatus": "DURING"
    },
    "@startDate": "2013-10-15T12:30:57.493Z",
    "description": "UserReconcile",
    "@distributionStrategy": "OFFER",
    "name": "UserReconcile",
    "itemContext": {
        "appName": "MyProcess",
        "appInstance": "pvm:0a12iq",
        "activityName": "UserReconcile",
        "appID": "_-hYCETV8EeOr4-yR8gXd7g",
        "activityID": "pvm:001im4"
    }
}
```

Can you spot the problem ?

Yes `activityID` is not a key of your `jsonObj` object.

You should do:

```
JSONObject itemContext = jsonObj.getJSONObject("itemContext");
String activityID = itemContext.getString("activityID");
```

Comment: I managed to find that way myself now :). I did jsonObj = getJSONObject("header").getJSONObject("itemContext")) and put that in a json obj, then use jsonObj.getString("activityID"); and that worked. Basically my problem was in understanding and identifying the json obj and navigating from the root down.  with this in mind, what happens if you dont know what your response is, say you get difference json responses. i suppose you could require the root object to identify like a messagetype and then parse from there?

Comment: Well, JSON is a data-interchange format, so both parties are supposed to agree beforehand to what data they will send to each other. If data format varies, you're screwed no matter what technology you are using.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
   "@priority":"50",
   "flags":{
      "scheduleStatus":"DURING"
   },
   "@startDate":"2013-10-15T12:30:57.493Z",
   "description":"UserReconcile",
   "@distributionStrategy":"OFFER",
   "name":"UserReconcile",
   "itemContext":{
      "appName":"MyProcess",
      "appInstance":"pvm:0a12iq",
      "activityName":"UserReconcile",
      "appID":"_-hYCETV8EeOr4-yR8gXd7g",
      "activityID":"pvm:001im4"
   }
}
```

this is your formatted JSON response , 
you are getting values for

```
priority=jsonObj.getString("@priority");
startDate =jsonObj.getString("@startDate");
workDesc=jsonObj.getString("description");
```

because they are directly available in the java object

but

```
amxref = jsonObj.getString("activityID");
```

fails because this is inside the Object called : **itemContext**

now please convert this in to JSONObject and then iterate it to get your desired element

Comment: thanks for reply, i managed to solve it. and you are correct.